# I have a querystring value which don't convert to right encoding?

Tags: asp.net, url-encoding

I pass actually Göte in the querystring parameter, which converts to G%F6te in the url field. 
And in the page, actually a generic handler it displays:

G�te

How to fix it, so it displays Göte?

**--------- EDIT ----------------**

*It actually works fine when I make a ajax-call to the page, but when I directly alter the querystring parameter it doesn't.*

Comment: dont forget to mark answwer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 0):

Make use of : [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

**Encoding**:

```
String MyURL;
MyURL = "http://www.contoso.com/articles.aspx?title=" + Server.UrlEncode("ASP.NET Examples");

Response.Write("<a href=" + MyURL + "> ASP.NET Examples </a>");
```

**Decoding**:

```
decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(urlToDecode)
```

Comment: I have tried both Server.UrlDecode and URLEncode and it doesn't work. It must be some other issue.